# getting a "relative" transform based upon scale

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have the below map. (posted in jsfiddle because too many characters for snippet)

[image: map picture]

https://jsfiddle.net/Tschallacka/n6cuxv7d/

I wish to scale the hawaiian islands up because at the moment they are too small and vanish in the big picture, especially on mobile.

Now I pieced together the below function to get a reliable 2 factor scale that works well across different formats.

```
var rect = $('[data-country-hasc="US.HI"]').get(0).getBBox();

var $hawaii = $('[data-country-hasc="US.HI"]');
var s = 2.0;
var t = [0- rect.x - ((rect.width * s) - rect.width),0-rect.y- ((rect.height * s) - rect.height )];

$hawaii.attr('transform', [
                        "translate(" + t + ")",
                        "scale(" + s + ")"
                    ].join(" "));
```

But what I need is a reliable way that scales the hawaiian islands with any given number for scale and that keeps them at the relative position they were at.

so if I were to give in a 2.5 or 3 for scale, it would still render at that position, but bigger.

To see the issue, see this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Tschallacka/dknojufd/

[image: hawaii on the move]

With a value of 2.2 hawaii is shifted to the right and bottom.

I do have access to the d3 path objects in my own project, but i'm not sure they are needed for this calculation.

Comment: I am unclear what you want to do that you are not already doing. You have a `translate()` adjustment in your transform. What else do you want?

Comment: change the scale value to 2.5 in the jsfiddle. Hawaii goes off the charts and doesn't stay "in position" because the coordinate system scales along, but I don't know how to account for the change in positioning system relative to the original positioning system so that for the "viewer" it will seem as if stays in place. See this one with scale 2.2 https://jsfiddle.net/Tschallacka/dknojufd/ hawaii has shifted to the right. I want it to stay in place, but become bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to scale something up (or down) around a specific point, is to add a transform that has three steps:

1. `translate()` to the origin (0,0)
2. `scale()`
3. `translate()` back to the desired location

So in your case, it would look something like:

```
var $hawaii = $('[data-country-hasc="US.HI"]');
var bbox = $hawaii.get(0).getBBox();

var cx = bbox.x + bbox.width/2;
var cy = bbox.y + bbox.height/2;
var s = 2;

$hawaii.attr('transform', "translate(" + [cx,cy] + ") " +
                          "scale(" + s + ") " +
                          "translate(" + [-cx,-cy] + ")");
```

In this example I've chosen the centre of Hawaii as the centre-point (cx,cy) of the scale.

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6cuxv7d/2/)

Comment: I did not know you could add translate twice. I knew it was a reset to 0, because I know that from 3d programming but I had no clue how to do that because I thought you could only add the translate thing once. Thanks!